# How to use hierarchical variable in a ML model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, classification, feature-selection

I am working on a binary classification problem with 1000 rows and 20 variables.

I have variables like `product_id`, `city`, `state`, `country`, `product family`, `product type`, `product segment` etc etc..

As you can see that most of my variables are hierarchical variables. Meaning, if I know the city name, I can infer/populate other variables like `state`, `country` etc.

Same with `product_id` as well. If I know `product_id` info, I can get all info about `product_family`, `product_segment`, `product type` etc.

My questions are as follows

a) So, should I use only the granular level detail variables in my ML model and ignore other levels of same variable? because I guess it would be correlated

b) Any suggestion or tips on how can we handle this scenario in our model?

c) Should I drop this project because I only have very few granular level detail variables (and rest of it can be inferred based on them even without using AI)?

d) If I make a prediction, I believe the contribution of hierarchical variable is same. For ex: If variable `city` contributes to prediction by 10%, am I right that `state`, `country` all contribute the same 10% as well. (meaning all together contribute 10% to the outcome)

Can you help me with this please?v Looking forward to your inputs

Comment: Is that Aurora, CO, or Aurora, IL? Or Aurora, Suriname, or Aurora, Victoria or… And no, if the city is 10% it doesn’t imply the state or country is 10%—if all the Auroras are Aurora, Santa Catarina, but the remaining 80% of the data isn’t Brazil…

Answer (score 0):

Of course you could use only granular level variables but this would throw away a lot of information.
The are different ways to leverage hierarchies.
One way would be target encoding as described [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/dealing-with-categorical-variables-by-using-target-encoder-a0f1733a4c69)
Another possible solution would be the use of a hierarchical model. An example for a hierarchical regression problem is described [here](https://num.pyro.ai/en/latest/tutorials/bayesian_hierarchical_linear_regression.html)